# Help with float right div

Tags: html, css

here is the page www.whiterootmedia.com.

I would like my ads on the right not to wrap and to get pushed off the screen at about 800px.
I think I need a wrap div container, float my ads div to the right, min-width my left div to 800px, but I have struggled getting this working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Dusty

Comment: ads look good to me at 800px on Chrome/FF/IE. did you fix this already?

Comment: That is one incredibly massive chunk of JS in the page... that should be stuffed into a seperate .js file, if only to keep the main page manageable.

Comment: not entirely sure what you mean. btw- what script do you use for the tree? i like.  Please eloborate more on the question.

Comment: scrunch the page and the ads wrap. I would like the ads to get pushed off the page when the width hits 800pxs and not to wrap.

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```
<div class="sitewrap">
      <div class="contentWrap"></div>
      <div class="adWrap">
</div>
```

use `float:left` on `contentWrap` and `adWrap`. Specify a `min-width` on `sitewrap` to ensure the content and ads fit without the ads wrapping. This will force scrolling if the viewport is narrower.